# Network Setup: Port not found?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have a computer that has an application that uses port 7001 which I would like to be able to access externally.

On my first setup it worked properly but soon an issue arises. there are too many of us connected! The network became congested which forced me to add anther router to act as another DHCP server but then something happened.

I can no longer access port 7001 externally!

I added the same port forwarding settings on the second router but it still didn't work..

here is how my setup looks like..

```
Router1(internet connected): IP 192.168.253.1 - used for connecting area1
Router2(connected to router1 via WAN): IP 192.168.254.1 - used for connecting area 3
Computer(the one with port 7001): IP 192.168.254.17 - located on area 2
```

Both router1 and router 2 has the port forwarding settings...

How do I resolve this?